# pulseaudio not loading properly

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My Ubuntu 18.04 PC has decided that pulseaudio is nothing good in the world, and therefore pulseaudio suddenly will stop seeing literally any audio devices-- quite literally, too, as `aplay -l` isn't returning with anything nice to say.

I've found that I keep getting that dreaded `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.` error, which spells no good news. `pulseaudio -v`, however, doesn't report the inotify issue, but instead pushes;

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

`pulseaudio -D` reported with the startup error, and running `pulseaudio -k` and `--start` consecutively do not work either.

I attempted to restart alsa with `sudo alsa force-reload`, though that did not help. Running `pacmd` responded with `Daemon not responding`, and not much else. `rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k` didn't help, either.

For a tl;dr, pulseaudio isn't loading my sound devices and no fixes I've seen are working.

**Edit for clarity as of 4/20/19:** I'd forgotten about this question, but I would like to point out some information I had missed that should be noted. *Restarting the computer does in fact fix the problem. It only happens occasionally when the Facebook Messenger call applet window is open on Firefox. Every once in a while, you will get a split second of audio from whatever was playing in the background when it happened.*

Comment: Bump? I want this fixed please.